# To determine whether there is a path between two points using C++ or C

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have an undirected graph represented by an adjacency matrix.

I need a high efficient code,the function just need to return true or false.

And I know [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) can work, I think I don't need the shortest path, and my adjacency matrix is:

```
a[i][j] = 1 or -1
```

There are no other values.

Comment: The [www.solvemyhomeworkforme.com](http://www.solvemyhomeworkforme.com) is a better fit.

Comment: You need to add algorithm tag to this question

Comment: There are BFS (breadth first search) and DFS (depth first search) algorithms that can serve your purposes.. Take a look at those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't notice your matrix only contains 0 and 1.

If only query once, maybe DFS or BFS is better, only `O(|V|+|E|)`

If it is bidirection path, `Disjoint-set data structure`([See wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)) is effective!

- single-source or multi-source?
- single-query or multi-query?

If there is only one query, all single-source shortest path algorithm is OK. Like:

- Bellman-Ford `O(|V||E|)`
- Dijkstra `O(|V|^2)`
- Dijkstra + Heap `Θ((|E|+|V|)log|V|)`
- SPFA (Bellman-Ford using queue)
- ...

If there are many queries, consider

- Floyd–Warshall algorithm `O(|V|^3)`

Comment: one query and bidirection path.

Comment: Worst case for `DFS` and `BFS` is `O(|E| + |V|)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know whether two points are connected or not, I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure will do the job about as quickly as you could hope. Start off with every point in its own set and then, for each link between two points, join the two sets to which those points belong.